# How to name this transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let the transformation be $T:\mathbf s\to \mathbf s'$, where both $\mathbf s$ and $\mathbf s'$ are of the form $(s_0, s_1, s_2, ..., s_n)$, and $s_i'=a_is_i$ for each $s_i$ in $\mathbf s$ and its corresponding $s_i'$ in $\mathbf s'$, and each $a_i$ is real.

So how to name that transformation? It is not **Scalar multiplication** since $a_i$ can differ from each other, is it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call it a *diagonal linear transformation*.